# C++ function that returns string, float or int

Tags: c++, g++

So I am over simplifying what I am trying to do here, but basically I have a function that looks like this:

```
int perform_operation(int left, std::string op, int right) {
    if (op == "+")
        return left + right;
    if (op == "-")
        return left - right;

    ... 

};
```

I want this function to be able to take in `float` , `int`, and `string` as left and right arguments.
If strings is passed in and the `+` operator is used, the strings should be concatenated, if a operator that does not support strings, it should throw an error.

I also want the function to be able to return both `float`, `int` and `string`.

Maybe this is impossible, if so please give me an advice on how to do this instead.

...

I am writing an interpreter if anyone is wondering.

Comment: Have you considered an variant? Boost or std::variant (c++17) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant

Comment: @schorsch_76 hmm that might be exactly what I need actually

Comment: "the strings should be concatenated" What strings? You only have one string.

Comment: What would the *return* type be for say the string and float case?

Comment: @schorsch_76 So I looked into std::variant and it does not seem to be fully supported yet :/ Otherwise, that would have been exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @Bathsheba If the string was completely numeric, it would convert it into appropriate type, otherwise it would be a string

Comment: @SebastianKarlsson: If you put that in the question, it becomes a good one.

Comment: Sorry but lastly, would the error you talk about be raised at compile time or at run time?

Comment: @Bathsheba The error should be raised at run time, but I have got this working now. Thank you anyways!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a function template.

```
template<class T>
T perform_operation(const T& left, std::string_view op, const T& right)
{
    if (op == "+")
        return left + right;
    if (op == "-")
        return left - right;

    // ...
}
```

Now as `std::string` does not support `operator -` and you want the operation to throw an error, you need to specialize the template for this type:

```
template<>
std::string perform_operation<std::string>(const std::string& left, std::string_view op, const std::string& right)
{
    if (op == "+")
        return left + right;

    throw std::invalid_argument("std::string supports operator + only");
}
```

This can be instantiated and invoked like the following.

```
const int result1 = perform_operation(1, "+", 2);
const float result2 = perform_operation(2.f, "-", 3.f);
const std::string result3 = perform_operation<std::string>("hello", "+", " world");

assert(result1 == 3);
assert(std::abs(result2 + 1.0f) < std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()));
assert(result3 == "hello world");
```

Note that I have changed the argument types to accept the operands as `const`-qualified references and the operator as `std::string_view` (a C++17 feature), but the latter isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why the question is downvoted, because this makes perfect sense in C++.

What you need is a `template`. Specifically, a function template.

```
template <typename T>
T perform_operation(T left, std::string op, T right) {
    if (op == "+")
        return left + right;
    if (op == "-")
        return left - right;
    // ... 
}
```

Of course, there's no `operator-` for templates, so you can use an overload:

```
std::string perform_operation(std::string left, std::string op, std::string right) {
    if (op == "+")
        return left + right;
   // ...
}
```

Comment: Has potential but methinks you need the trailing return type syntax and some kind of metaprogramming technique to derive that based on the types of the two arguments. And everyone likes to see trailing return types from time to time.

Comment: @Bathsheba: I could dig up the `numeric2` header we've got in use over here, but that seemed a bit overkill.

Comment: But you'd get +90 at least.

Comment: Would be a a worse answer, though, because it would be no longer at the level of the question. Some of the return type deductions in there are _scary_. (Doesn't help that they're C++11; folding will eventually help clean them up.)